# Working copy lost link to Subversion

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Today my Subversion working folder no longer has the Windows Explorer icons on the files and folders, and when I try to commit in Windows Explorer or Visual Studio, it shows there are no versioned files. However, it all worked this morning.

I've verified the `.svn` folder is still in the root of the working copy. I didn't install any Subversion updates or delete any files in the folder (intentionally). My project works just fine, with no problems, it's just the project is no longer under version control and I can no longer commit my code.

I ran the `svn cleanup` command on the working copy and it said the svn database is corrupt (I'll try to post exact error message if I can find it).

I understand I can checkout my project in a new directory and perform a diff between that and my "broken" working directory, and manually merge the project into the new, versioned directory. However, is there a way I "re-link" my old working copy back to my Subversion repository without loosing all my recent, uncommitted changes?

Comment: Telling out if it's just a TortoiseSVN issue is not that hard. The installer contains command-line binaries as optional component and something as simple as `svn info` can highlight certain issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing was checking out the project in a *different* directory, and using Beyond Compare to find the differences between the two projects and copy the changed files only to the newly checked-out version. Note, I only migrated the versioned files (in my case, web app files such as cs, cshtml, js, vs project files, etc.) and did not copy `svn` related files.

I was then able to open the project and check in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remove the hidden `.svn` directory at the root of the working copy? The working copy can't "lose the link" (i.e. become *unversioned*) by itself.

You should be able to solve the problem this way:

1. Copy the current working copy somewhere else to act as a backup in case something goes wrong (you don't want to lose your uncommitted changes, do you?).
2. Run `svn checkout` to the same directory which is now unversioned.

Comment: The `.svn` directory in the root of the working copy is still there. I do not want to loose my uncommitted changes. Will checking out the project again on-top of my changes overwrite them?

Comment: Do you know of any way to "checkout" just the `.svn` folder?

Comment: @Andrew Why do you ask? You'd better post a new question about your task.

Comment: @bahrep It's basically the same problem as this question. When I create repos they're not linked to the SVN and I have to check out all of the files I just committed to the new repo. Would be nice to just be able to export that `.svn` directory.

Comment: @Andrew You can run `svn checkout` into the directory which you imported to svn and it will create the `.svn` dir. Try this approach with a test repo. I'm not sure that I understand your case, though. I recommend that you post a new question instead of commenting.

Comment: @bahrep Yeah and it will check out 1,000 files besides that `.svn` directory as well.